# AWS logs agent setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We have recently setup AWS logs agent on one of our test servers. Our log files usually contain multi-line events. e.g one of our log event is:

```
[10-Jun-2016 07:30:16 UTC] SQS Post Response: Array
(
    [Status] => 200
    [ResponseBody] => <?xml version="1.0"?><SendMessageResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-02-01/"><SendMessageResult><MessageId>053c7sdf5-1e23-wa9d-99d8-2a0cf9eewe7a</MessageId><MD5OfMessageBody>8e542d2c2a1325a85eeb9sdfwersd58f</MD5OfMessageBody></SendMessageResult><ResponseMetadata><RequestId>4esdfr30-c39b-526b-bds2-14e4gju18af</RequestId></ResponseMetadata></SendMessageResponse>
)
```

The log agent reference documentation says to use 'multi_line_start_pattern' option for such logs. Our AWS Log agent config is as follows:

```
[httpd_info.log]
file = /var/log/httpd/info.log*
log_stream_name = info.log
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = test.server.name
multi_line_start_pattern = '(\[)+\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}+-\d{4}'
```

However, the logs agent reporting breaks on aforementioned and similar events. The way it is being reported to CloudWatch Logs is as follows:

Event 1:

```
[10-Jun-2016 11:21:26 UTC] SQS Post Response: Array
```

Event 2:

```
( [Status] => 200 [ResponseBody] => <?xml version="1.0"?><SendMessageResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-02-01/"><SendMessageResult><MessageId>053c7sdf5-1e23-wa9d-99d8-2a0cf9eewe7a</MessageId><MD5OfMessageBody>8e542d2c2a1325a85eeb9sdfwersd58f</MD5OfMessageBody></SendMessageResult><ResponseMetadata><RequestId>4esdfr30-c39b-526b-bds2-14e4gju18af</RequestId></ResponseMetadata></SendMessageResponse>
```

Event 3:

```
)
```

Despite of the fact that its only a single event. Any clue whats going on here?

Answer (score 6):

I think all you need to add is the following to your awslogs.conf

```
datetime_format = %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S UTC
time_zone = UTC
multi_line_start_pattern = {datetime_format}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html

multi_line_start_pattern

Specifies the pattern for identifying the start of a log message. A log message is made of a line that matches the pattern and any following lines that don't match the pattern. The valid values are regular expression or {datetime_format}. When using {datetime_format}, the datetime_format option should be specified. The default value is ‘^[^\s]' so any line that begins with non-whitespace character closes the previous log message and starts a new log message.

If that datetime format didn't work, you would need to update your regex to actually match your specific datetime. I don't think the one you have listed above actually works for your given format.

You could try this for instance:

[\d{2}-[\w]{3}-\d{4}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s{1}\w+]

does match

[10-Jun-2016 11:21:26 UTC]

See here: http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=96811

Once completed, issue a restart of the service and check to see if its parsing correctly.

$ sudo service awslogs restart